# Using max-function in subquery relating to main query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem:
I have two tables `TAB_1` and `TAB_2`.

In `TAB_1` I would like to fill in column `FEAT_A1` with a matching value in `TAB_2`. Hence, I join both tables on their common feature `FEAT_B`.

Unfortunately, per `FEAT_B2`-ID in `TAB_2` there are multiple records. I would like to use the matching record, for which `FEAT_D2` is maximal.

I can perform this operation with the code shown below. Unfortunately, the code is super slow since, per match, I have to perform one order- and one fetch-operation.

Can you think of a more efficient way to program this?

To clarify things, here is an example of `TAB_2` records:

```
FEAT_A2     FEAT_B2    FEAT_C2         FEAT_D2
"A"           42      "SOMETHING"        7
"B"           42      "SOMETHING"        11
"D"           42      "SOMETHING"        1
"A"           42      "SOMETHING"        3
```

In `TAB_1`, for `FEAT_B1 = 42`, I would like to set `FEAT_A1 = "B"`.

```
UPDATE TAB_1
SET TAB_1.FEAT_A1 = (
    SELECT FEAT_A2 FROM TAB_2
    WHERE TAB1.FEAT_B1 = TAB2.FEAT_B2
        AND TAB2.FEAT_C2 = 'SOMETHING'
    ORDER BY TAB2.FEAT_D2 DESC
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
UPDATE TAB_1
    SET TAB_1.FEAT_A1 =
        (SELECT FEAT_A2
         FROM TAB_2
         WHERE TAB1.FEAT_B1 = TAB2.FEAT_B2 AND
               TAB2.FEAT_C2 = 'SOMETHING'
         ORDER BY TAB2.FEAT_D2 DESC
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
        );
```

You want an index on `tab_2(FEAT_B1, FEAT_C2, FEAT_D2 DESC)`.  This should be a notable performance improvement.

That said, you are going to be updating all rows in `TAB_1`.  If that table is no small, then there will be a lot of overhead just for doing the updates.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `merge` for it.

```
MERGE INTO TAB_1 T1
USING (SELECT FEAT_A2, FEAT_B2,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FEAT_B2 
                                 ORDER BY FEAT_D2 DESC NULLS LAST) AS RN
         FROM TAB_2) T2
ON (T1.FEAT_B1 = T2.FEAT_B2 AND T2.RN = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET T1.FEAT_A1 = T2.FEAT_A2
```

Cheers!!